# How to get data from server before component is mounted vue2.0

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've got a question like in the title 
How to stop mounting the component in `<router-view>` until receive a data from server or how to get the data before the component is mounted to `<router-view>`

My files:

1st main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { Login, Start },
  data: function(){
    return{
      info: null,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    bef: function(){
      this.$http.get('xxx').then(function(response){
        return response.body
      });
    }
  },
  beforeMount(){
    this.info= this.bef()
  }
})
```

2nd component file Comp.vue

```
export default{
    name: 'start',
    data(){
        return{

        }
    },
    beforeMount(){
       console.log(this.$parent.info)
    }
}
```

how to do it properly to get not null value, but response from the server?
Thank you in advance

Comment: resolved with:
return new Promise((resolve, reject) = >{
});

Answer (score 0):

resolved with:

```
checkLogged: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
          this.$http.get('xxx').then(response => {
            if (response.body == 1) {
              resolve(true);
            } else {
              resolve(false);
            }
          }, response => {
            reject('connection failure');
          });
        });
    },
```

and in 2nd file:

```
this.$root.checkLogged().then((response) => {
            if(response){
                this.logged = true
            }else{
                router.push("/")
            }
        })
```